# How can I get the hinge animation to work on the image with a click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know some of you guys are pros, I have gotten a comment or two (though usually constructive) on previous posts, so please just understand that I am a bit lost as to why this animation is not working, and sure it may be simple enough for you, but I am trying to learn.

I feel like this is a mess.  I added a ton of css code that I hadn't been using per a tutorial instruction, but effectively, I feel like this should be a super simple thing.  I have an image, I want to use the hinge animation upon clicking the button.  I went from a handful of lines of code to this monstrosity per the tutorial:

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<!--  Added jQuery lib  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").click(function() {
                $("body").addClass("animated hinge");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        /* ANIMATION CLASSES for the HINGE effect ONLY */

        .css-transition {-webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out; -ms-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out; transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out;}

        @-webkit-keyframes hinge{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);-webkit-transform-origin:top left;-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{-webkit-transform:rotate(80deg);-webkit-transform-origin:top left;-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%{-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);-webkit-transform-origin:top left;-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}80%{-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg) translateY(0);opacity:1;-webkit-transform-origin:top left;-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(700px);opacity:0}}
        @-moz-keyframes hinge{0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0);-moz-transform-origin:top left;-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{-moz-transform:rotate(80deg);-moz-transform-origin:top left;-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%{-moz-transform:rotate(60deg);-moz-transform-origin:top left;-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}80%{-moz-transform:rotate(60deg) translateY(0);opacity:1;-moz-transform-origin:top left;-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}100%{-moz-transform:translateY(700px);opacity:0}}
        @-o-keyframes hinge{0%{-o-transform:rotate(0);-o-transform-origin:top left;-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{-o-transform:rotate(80deg);-o-transform-origin:top left;-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%{-o-transform:rotate(60deg);-o-transform-origin:top left;-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}80%{-o-transform:rotate(60deg) translateY(0);opacity:1;-o-transform-origin:top left;-o-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}100%{-o-transform:translateY(700px);opacity:0}}
        @keyframes hinge{0%{transform:rotate(0);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}20%,60%{transform:rotate(80deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}40%{transform:rotate(60deg);transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}80%{transform:rotate(60deg) translateY(0);opacity:1;transform-origin:top left;animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}100%{transform:translateY(700px);opacity:0}}

        .animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;-moz-animation-duration:2s;-o-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s}

        .hinge{-webkit-animation-name:hinge;-moz-animation-name:hinge;-o-animation-name:hinge;animation-name:hinge}

        #drop {
            position: relative;
        }

        .button {
            width: 100px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            display: inline-block;
            font: Arial;
            margin-left: 500px;
            color: black;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        button:hover {
            background: #9ff;
        }

        button:active {
            background: #fff;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
        }

        button:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<img id="drop" src="https://alualuna.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/tekkonkinkreet.jpg">
<button id="hinge" class="button">Kill It</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?  Thank you!

Comment: As you can see by your self I added only the jQuery lib and your html works!

Comment: Thank you gaetano.  So the first go, I inserted the cdn link within the script tag, and left all the jquery stuff in one script section (all put together properly).  It did not run.  Then I did what you did, closed the script after the cdn, and then used a second script section for the jquery code.  It worked.  Can you please explain why this makes a difference?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the `jQuery` library in your `<head>` section.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```